# Can anybody supply a list of the 1560 possible contiguous, orthogonally connected configurations of three identical 2 x 4 lego bricks?

Tags: combinatorics, recursive-algorithms

I have written a program to solve the lego counting problem - to count the number of different contiguous geometric structures that can be made from n identical 4 x 2 lego bricks, all connected orthogonally. the problem is solved for n up to 10 by Soren Eilers and others, see [here](http://oeis.org/A112389).

My problem gives approximately the same answers as on that link, and match exactly for 1 and 2 bricks - giving 1 and 24 possibilities respectively.

But I get 1550 possibilities  for 3 bricks whereas Eilers and others get 1560 bricks. For greater n they diverge further, but not massively. I have looked over my code and fixed a number of problems but cannot see any remaining errors. The only way I can see to fix the errors is to get a list of the 1560 n=3 configurations and compare it to the list of configurations my program generates.

For larger n it's not practical to generate a list of configs, because the number is so large. For instance n=6 gives 915m+ possibilities. But printing the approx 1.5k possibilities for n=3 is easy.

Does anybody know where I could find either a list of the configs, or a program that does the counting, which I could adapt to print out all configs found, then compare the list to my own?

I thought this question could go in the maths SE, on stack overflow, or on the "bricks" SE (for lego enthusiasts). I took a guess this might be the best one. IIRC SE discourages cross-posting.

thank you

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the Lego counting problem, so I won't be able to help directly.  However, there may be a way to use mathSE to solve the problem.  It is almost never a good idea to post *software code* on mathSE; reviewers will consider this beyond the scope of the website.  **However, if** you are able to boil your code down to approximately 10-15 (maximum) lines of **pseudocode**, that merely demonstrate the logic of your code, a mathSE reviewer who happens to be knowledgeable in Lego blocks may look at it.  I emphasize, **no actual code**, and keep the pseudocode **short**.

Comment: The alternative approach is to pretend that you were giving a mathematical analysis of the problem, and you explained each step that you took, in **extremely clear** mathematical language, so that you *changed* your query from analyzing code to analyzing mathematical analysis, that might also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved this problem, and have my own list of the 1560 configurations. I also have lists for configurations of 4 and of 5 blocks - both with cardinalities that match oeis.org. If you are working on this problem and would like to compare lists, contact me by message on this stackexchange platform.